# Angular watch not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A'
        , link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var c = 0;

            function stuff() {
                console.log('==== compute ====');
                return { 'c' : c };
            }

            scope.$on('Test', function(event) {
                c += 1;
                console.log('++++broadcast received++++ phase:',  scope.$$phase);
            });

            scope.$watch(stuff(), function () {
                console.log('-----Seen-----');
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Elsewhere in a controller on another scope I am broadcasting, the "On" here above is receiving the broadcast, I am getting the logged entry.
But the Watch is never firing when this happens, "stuff" is not called.
The $$phase reports $apply too.

How many things have I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `scope.$watch(stuff, ...)`. without parentheses. based on the demo code by @marck (thanks):

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var c = 0;

    function stuff() {
      console.log('==== compute ====');
      return {
        'c': c
      };
    }

    scope.$on('Test', function(event) {
      c += 1;
      console.log('c=',c);
    });

    scope.$watch(stuff, function(u,v) {
      console.log(u,v);
    }, true);

    scope.cPlusOne = function() {
      scope.$emit('Test');
    };

  }
```

Comment: $watchCollection(stuff, ...) could also be used in place of $watch(stuff, ..., true);

Answer (score -1):

`$watch` watches for changes of scope variables. With `$watch(stuff()...` you call `stuff` and let angular watch what stuff returns. Which is `{c:c}`.